# Update a table with data from other table with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have a table called `A` and it has `ARTICLE_NUMBER` and `NEWCOLUMN` columns. Also, I have another table called `B` that has ARTICLENUMBER and `EVENT` columns. I want to execute an update statement for my `NEWCOLUMN` Column.

If `EVENT` at Table `B` is `NULL`, my `NEWCOLUMN` column should be `0` and if `EVENT` at Table `B` is `NOT NULL`, my `NEWCOLUMN` column should be `1`.

I've tried the following, but unfortunately it didn't work;

```
UPDATE A a
INNER JOIN B b 
    ON a.ARTICLENUMBER = b.ARTICLENUMBER
SET
    a.NEWCOLUMN = CASE WHEN b.EVENT IS NULL THEN 0
                       WHEN b.EVENT IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                  END;
```

Can someone maybe help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you really want `EXISTS` -- that is to set *all* values in table `A`, with `1` if there is a non-`NULL` matching event.  That would be:

```
UPDATE A
    SET NEWCOLUMN = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                       FROM B
                                       WHERE b.ARTICLENUMBER = a.ARTICLENUMBER AND
                                             b.EVENT IS NOT NULL
                                        )
                          THEN 1 ELSE 0
                      END);
```

Note that this updates *all* rows in `A` -- even those with no matching article in `B`.  As I say, I *think* this is what you want to do, although it is not exactly how your question is phrased.  Your question does not specify what to do for `ARTICLENUMBER`s that are not in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support this MySQL-style update join syntax.  But, you may express your update using a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE A a
SET NULLBESTAND = (SELECT CASE WHEN b.EVENT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                   FROM B b
                   WHERE b.ARTICLENUMBER = a.ARTICLENUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I presume:

```
update a set a.newcolumn = 
  (select case when b.event is null then 0
               when b.event is not null then 1
          end
   from b
   where b.article_number = a.article_number)
where exists (select null from b
              where b.article_number = a.article_number);
```

Or merge:

```
merge into a
  using b
  on (a.article_number = b.article_number)
  when matched then update set
    a.newcolumn = case when b.event is null then 0
                       when b.event is not null then 1
                  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have two updates.

```
UPDATE A
SET NEWCOLUMN = 0
WHERE ARTICLENUMBER IN (select ARTICLENUMBER from B where EVENT IS NULL);
UPDATE A
SET NEWCOLUMN = 1
WHERE ARTICLENUMBER IN (select ARTICLENUMBER from B where EVENT IS NOT NULL);
```

As always, make sure you have the proper indexes.